# How to include one angularjs based SPA into another angularjs based SPA using nested ng-app which are attached to html tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-app

Angular module is defined as :

```
angular.module('module1',['ngRoute']);
```

Route for *module1* is defined as

```
 module1.config(function($routeProvider) 
 {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/Application1',
       {
            templateUrl: 'Application1/Application1_HomePage.html',
       })         
      .otherwise({
          templateUrl: 'MainPage.html',
          controller: 'ctrl'
      )}
 });
```

And the controller *ctrl* is defined as:

```
 module1.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$location)
 {
         $scope.goToApp1 = function()
         {
              $location.path('/Application1',true);
         }
 });
```

The shell page is as :

```
<html ng-app="module1">
   <body>
      <div ng-view>   </div>                   
   </body>
</html>
```

Application1_HomePage.html contains another ng-app than the shell page ng-app *module1*.

From the shell page shown above, when a call to Application1_HomePage.html  is made through routeProvider, initialization of ng-app written inside Application1_HomePage.html is failing. The browser inspector clearly shows nothing out of the DOM.

Considering the above scenario how can I make a navigation from one ng-app to another ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of the modules have an entrance page you can just put a link to the other app page, for example:

you load module1Index.html and on that page you put an link to module2Index.html:

```
<a href="http://module2.com"></a>
```

If you need both modules to sit on the same page , just include one in the other:

```
angular.module('module1', ['module2']);
```

Comment: Am new to angular.  _If_ the OP _could_ (re)move the `ng-app` from `html` and say scope each to their own `div`, wouldn't that also be an option?

Comment: @EdSF - you have to tell angular what is the app module, either by defining ng-app, or by initializing it through JS.

Comment: Understood, so `<div ng-app="app1">` and another `<div ng-app="app2">` each with their own areas of responsibility (instead of scoping the entire thing in one app because `ng-app` was defined in the top level `<html>`)?

Comment: @EdSF - no, you can't have 2 ng-app for the same angular application, if you have 2 different index pages then you can do it, otherwise, include one module as a dependency of the other.

Comment: @fatman - I already tried  injecting one module into another, but that did not work  and  browser inspector did not show anything related to the injected module.